# Finding the moment generating function for an absolute normal distribution

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions

Another exam review question.

Suppose I know $Z \sim \text{N}(0,1)$, $Y=|Z|$. And I want to find the moment generating function $M_{Y}(t)$. In our notes it's just given to us as $2 N(t) e^{\frac{t^{2}}{2}}$ where $N(t)$ is the c.d.f. of a $N(0,1)$ random variable, but I felt like for practicing mgfs it could be good to derive it. That being said, I don't even know where to start. I feel like starting with the normal p.d.f., but from there I don't know where to simplify, if that's the right approach. Maybe MacLaurin series?

Comment: Hint: the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) allows you to compute $E[e^{tY}] = E[e^{t|X|}]$ if you know the distribution of $X$ (which you do in this case).

Comment: @DilipSarwate Hmm. I'm still not really catching on. I should take the derivative of the c.d.f. you're saying?

Comment: $$E[e^{t|X|}] = \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-tx}f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx + \int_0^\infty e^{-tx}f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$ Now "complete the square" in the exponent of each integral which should pop out a $e^{t^2/2}$ from each integral and the integrals should give you a normal CDF value..

Comment: @DilipSarwate Apologies for really still being stuck. I replaced each $f_{X}(x)$ with the normal (0,1) probability density function, but I couldn't get any factor to come out. I just end up with a tricky $e$ term over $\sqrt{2\pi}$... what am I missing?

Comment: For instance $\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^{2} - tz}$

Comment: $$\exp(-tx)\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) = \exp\left(-\frac{(x+t)^2}{2} + \frac{t^2}{2}\right) = \exp\left(-\frac{(x+t)^2}{2}\right)\exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\right)$$ where the first term in that expression on the right stays inside the integral and the second term can be pulled outside the integral. Similarly for the other integral. OK, no more hints. If you still cannot figure it out, wait for someone else to come and write out a full answer for you.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Got it, thanks a lot for your help. Curiously harder than I imagined.