# Error in proof of MGF of standard half normal distribution?

Tags: probability, integration, moment-generating-functions

I'm not getting the standard answer of but I'm not sure what's wrong with my reasoning. Any insight appreciated.

Let $Z \sim N(0,1)$. We want to find the MGF of $\left|Z\right|$. By definition:

$$\psi_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{t\left|z\right|}f_z(z)dz$$

Then since $e^{t\left|z\right|}f_z(z)$ is a product of two even functions, it is also an even function, so it's symmetrical around the y-axis and:

$$\psi_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tz}f_z(z)dz$$

Now we can substitute in the PDF definition:

$$\psi_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tz}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}dz$$

Now we can do some plain old algebra:

$$\psi_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tz}e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2}dz$$

$$\psi_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2 + tz}dz$$

$$e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\cdot\psi_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2 + tz}dz$$

$$e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\cdot\psi_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}z^2 + tz - \frac{1}{2}t^2}dz$$

$$e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\cdot\psi_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(z^2 - 2tz + t^2)}dz$$

$$e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\cdot\psi_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(z-t)^2}dz$$

Put that aside for a moment. From the fact that PDF formula for the normal distribution sums to 1 it is possible to deduce that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2}dx = \sigma\sqrt{2\pi}$$

Then since the function is even we can infer:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu)^2}dx = \frac{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}$$

So now we can go back, using $\sigma=1,  \mu=t$:

$$e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}\cdot\psi_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}$$

Cancelling gives us:

$$\psi_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = e^{\frac{1}{2}t^2}$$

Then to double check my answer I take the derivative and plug in 0, expecting to get $\mathbb{E}(\left|Z\right|) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$.

$$\psi'_{\left|Z\right|}(t) = te^{\frac{1}{2}t^2}$$
$$\psi'_{\left|Z\right|}(0) = 0$$

Not what I expected. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Since you applied the substitution $u = z-t$, the domain of integration shifts to $(-t, \infty)$. The final answer will therefore involve the [*error function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: @SangchulLee oh of course. I've been dealing with u substitution in integrals from negative to positive infinity a lot where transforming the bounds doesn't matter so I missed it. You should post as an answer so I can mark correct.

Comment: Let me also add that$\psi_{|Z|} (t) =e^{\frac 12 t^{2}}$ cannot hold for negative $t$ since LHS $<1$ and RHS $>1$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I have edited my proof to not use the u substitution, and so avoiding the problem with needing to change the range of the integral but I still get the same answer.

Comment: The final answer seems to be $2\Phi(t)e^{t^2/2}$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482088/finding-the-moment-generating-function-for-an-absolute-normal-distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Let the standard normal density function be $\phi(u)$ and the cumulative distribution function be $\Phi(u)$. Then the final answer is, as given in a comment, $2\Phi(t) e^{\frac12 t^2} $

To sum it up:
\begin{eqnarray}
M_{|U|}(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{t|u|} \phi(u)\; du \\
           &=2 \int_0^\infty e^{t|u|} \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac12 u^2}\;du \\
           &=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac12 t^2} \int_0^\infty e^{-\frac12 (u-t)^2} \; du \\
           &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac12 t^2} \int_{-t}^\infty e^{-\frac12 z^2}\: dz \\
   &= 2\Phi(t) e^{\frac12 t^2} 
\end{eqnarray}